# Can anyone help on this Code which i'm writing in the VF page, it's throwing Syntax error. Extra ','

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:outputtext value="{!IF(AND(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Loan_Product_Name__c =='Working Capital'),
OR((disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Cleared_Disbursal_Txn_Count__c >1),
(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Contract_Type__c=='Refinance'))), ROUND(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.Broker_Commision__c*0.5,2),
IF(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.Broker_Commision__c == null, 0.00, ROUND(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.Broker_Commision__c,2)
)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The first IF condition is not closed correctly. Can you try below option.

```
IF(

AND(
disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Loan_Product_Name__c =='Working Capital',
OR(
(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Cleared_Disbursal_Txn_Count__c >1)
,
(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.loan__Contract_Type__c=='Refinance')
)

),
ROUND(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.Broker_Commision__c*0.5,2),

IF(
disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.Broker_Commision__c == null, 0.00,ROUND(disbursal.loan__Loan_Account__r.Broker_Commision__c,2)
))
```

Comment: I want to check first IF condition is true do the calculation after that, otherwise 2nd IF condition. Is this code correct for this criteria?

Comment: For the above changes which u suggested also throwing error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4

Comment: Yes. With the above logic it will check the first IF condition and enter into the second one. Can you try the above answer once.  Here is the same example for mulitple IF conditions. 
IF(Product.name = "X",A*B,
IF(Product.name ="Y",A*B*C,
IF(Product.name= "Z",A*B*C*D,
A
)))

Comment: I updated the answer. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. This worked. @KSL

Comment: Great!! If it works for you please accept the answer